# Generic optional enum func

Tags: swift, generics, enums, option-type

In my project I have a couple of enums which I use everywhere, these enums are created based on external json, so input is always optional. If an enum can't be created from the input, I'll define a default value.

Example of how I do things now:

```
enum TextAlign:String {
    case left, center, right
}

let rawData = [String:Any]()

func getTextAlign() -> TextAlign {
    if let rawTextAlignString = rawData["textAlign"] as? String, let align = TextAlign(rawValue: rawTextAlignString) {
        return align
    }

    return TextAlign.left
}
let textAlign = self.getTextAlign()
```

This works obviously, but I would like to make my constructor a bit more swifty, generic and applicable to more of these enums. My goal is to instantiate these enums like this:

```
let textAlign = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: rawData["textAlign"] as? String) ?? TextAlign.left
```

So I basically want a failable initializer, which I can just write for the TextAlign enum, but there has to be a way to declare this in a more 'generic' way so that I can use the initializer on all of my enum:String instances. 
I'm struggeling a bit with the syntax and options of generics in swift.

Any idea?

## Update #1

I see a lot of answers which are all not wrong, but probably I wasn't clear enough in what I'm looking for.

I have more enums like this:

```
enum TextAlign:String {
    case left, center, right
}

enum CornerRadius:String {
    case none, medium, large
}

enum Spacing:String {
    case tight, medium, loose
}
```

I would like to define just 1 function that can initialize all these enums. (not because I'm lazy, but because I want to understand how to use Generics for this)

Probably what I need is some static func in an extension that applies to all these 'String/RawRepresentable' enums. I don't want to write all these failable initializers for each enum. (I believe it should be possible but I can't figure out the syntax)

## Update #2

After playing a bit with Joakim's answer I came up with the following solution:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    static func create<T:Any>(_ value: Any?, defaultValue: Self) -> Self where Self.RawValue == T {
        guard let rawValue = value as? T, let instance = Self.init(rawValue: rawValue) else {
            return defaultValue
        }

        return instance
    }
}
```

This allows me to instantiate enums of type `String` and `Int` (and more) with this function. Like this:

```
enum TextAlign:String {
    case left, center, right
}

enum CornerRadius:Int {
    case none, medium, large
}

let json:[String:Any] = [
    "textAlign":"left",
    "cornerRadius":0
]

let cornerRadius = CornerRadius.create(json["cornerRadius"], defaultValue: .medium)
let align = TextAlign.create(json["textAlign"], defaultValue: .center)
```

I like that I can just pas `Any?` as an argument and that it takes care of the casting on its own by doing `let rawValue = value as? T`.

## Update #3 (solution)

Okay, the complexcity of it all still bothered me a bit, so I tried the init route, which imo, looks way cleaner. The whole thing now looks like this:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init(from value: Any?, or defaultValue: Self) {
        self = Self.init(from: value) ?? defaultValue
    }

    init?(from value: Any?) {
        guard let rawValue = value as? Self.RawValue, let instance = Self.init(rawValue: rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }

        self = instance
    }
}
```

I created a failable and a non-failable init with a default value for convenience purposes.

Now I can just instantiate any enum like this:

```
let cornerRadius = CornerRadius(json["cornerRadius"], or: .medium)

// or an optional one
let align = TextAlign(json["textAlign"])
```

Now I'm done with the updates...

Comment: It's not clear. You're asking for a generic way, but some of your comments suggest that you want to initialize like TextAlign(...), etc, but that's not generic.

Comment: Yes. I'm asking for a generic way and if possible I would like to initialize like that. If it's not possible, then not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function you can use to create enum items from a string

```
func createEnumItem<T: RawRepresentable>(_ value: String) -> T? where T.RawValue == String {
    return  T.init(rawValue: value)
}
```

and then use it like

```
let textAlign: TextAlign = createEnumItem("right")!
let radius: CornerRadius = createEnumItem("medium")!
```

Note that you always include the enum type in the variable declaration.

Of course since the return value is optional you need to handle that in a better way than my example here.

**Update**

In case you always know what your default is here is a modified version

```
func createEnumItem<T: RawRepresentable>(_ value: String, withDefault defaultItem: T) -> T where T.RawValue == String {
    guard let item = T.init(rawValue: value) else {
        return defaultItem
    }
    return item
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for, but! I would prefer to call it like `TextAlign.create(...)` and `CornerRadius.create(...)`. Should be possible right?

Comment: Or.. even better, just using `TextAlign(...)` and `CornerRadius(...)`. Not sure if possible to define an initializer like this actually.

Comment: Yes of courser but it wouldn't be generic then and if you want to create an init method like this it's just a simple wrapper around the default one.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one as I derived my final solution from yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your enums like this

```
enum TextAlign: String {
    case left, center, right

    init(rawOptionalValue: String?) {
        self = TextAlign(rawValue: rawOptionalValue ?? TextAlign.left.rawValue) ?? .left
    }
}
```

And then instantiate it like this:

```
let textAlign = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: rawData["textAlign"] as? String)
```

### Update

Here's one example with a default value as an optional parameter as well:

```
enum TextAlign: String {
    case left, center, right

    init(rawOptionalValue: String?, defaultValue: TextAlign = TextAlign.left) {
        self = TextAlign(rawValue: rawOptionalValue ?? defaultValue.rawValue) ?? defaultValue
    }
}

let textAlign1 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "left") // .left
let textAlign2 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "right") // .right
let textAlign3 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "center") // .center
let textAlign4 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "notAnAlignment") // .left
let textAlign5 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: nil, defaultValue: .center) // .center
```

### Update 2

Ok, now I understand. Well then based on your latest update you can also do this I guess:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init(rawOptionalValue: Any?, defaultValue: Self) {
        guard let value = rawOptionalValue as? Self.RawValue else {
            self = defaultValue
            return
        }
        self = Self.init(rawValue: value) ?? defaultValue
    }
}
```

The only thing here compared to my previous try is that you cannot provide a default `defaultValue`. So you would use it like this:

```
let textAlign1 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "left", defaultValue: .left) // .left
let textAlign2 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "right", defaultValue: .left) // .right
let textAlign3 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "center", defaultValue: .left) // .center
let textAlign4 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: "notAnAlignment", defaultValue: .left) // .left
let textAlign5 = TextAlign(rawOptionalValue: nil, defaultValue: .center) // .center
```

Comment: Why do you make this init a failable init, when it can never possible fail?

Comment: All very valid, but not what I'm looking for, please check my update in my question.

Comment: I see. Based on your update I've added another "solution" :)

Comment: Hah, which is pretty much identical. Nice solution though :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a new function for this. Just use [`Optional.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map):

```
let alignment = rawData["textAlign"].map(TextAlign.init(rawValue:)) ?? .left
```

Comment: I don't dislike it, but I'd prefer a bit more of a cleaner initializer (see update #3). Thanks.

Comment: @GertjanSmits Fair enough. But I would discourage `or: .medium` argument. Nil coalescence is a concise and well understood feature. I would recommend `CornerRadius(json["cornerRadius"]) ?? .medium` over `CornerRadius(json["cornerRadius"], or: .medium)`

Comment: I agree actually, but it's really a convenience thing. For this reason I also created the `init?()`. I have to choose the right `init` for the job, sometimes the optional _is_ what I want, in other cases I just want to `switch` on an unwrapped (with default) enum.

Comment: Exactly. Swift has lots of facilities for dealing with optionals. (`!`, `??`, conditional binding, pattern matching, `Optional.map`, `Optional.flatMap`, etc.). It doesn't make sense making wrapper APIs around such common facilities

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 let textAlign = TextAlign(rawValue: rawData["textAlign"] as? String ?? TextAlign.left.rawValue)
```

Comment: I thought of this, and had it at some point, but it's not good enough :). The value coming from the `rawData`, can be a `String` in this case, but that doesn't mean that it's a valid one. In your example `let textAlign` is still an optional `TextAlign` instance, because the `TextAlign:rawValue` initializer is a failable one. Which means you have to append `?? TextAlign.left` at the end of the line to unwrap it. Which I believe makes it a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static func like so and use it everywhere you need in your code

```
enum TextAlign: String {
    case left, center, right

    static func getTextAlign(rawData: [String:Any]) -> TextAlign {
        if let rawTextAlignString = rawData["textAlign"] as? String, let align = TextAlign(rawValue: rawTextAlignString) {
            return align
        }

        return TextAlign.left
    }
}

// Test
var myRawData = [String:Any]()

let textAlign1 = TextAlign.getTextAlign(rawData: myRawData) // left

myRawData["textAlign"] = "center"

let textAlign2 = TextAlign.getTextAlign(rawData: myRawData) // center
```